# C++ error enum and CRTP

Tags: c++, enums, crtp

```
template<class T>
struct broker
{
    typedef T typeBroker;
    static std::vector<std::string> extractListBroker(const std::string& broker)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> vec;

        if(broker.empty())          
        {
            for(int i=0;i<typeBroker::nbBroker;++i)
                vec.push_back( typeBroker::listBroker[i] );         
        }           
        else
        {
            typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > my_tok;

            boost::char_separator<char> sep( ";" );

            my_tok tok( broker, sep );

            for ( my_tok::const_iterator i = tok.begin(); i != tok.end(); ++i )  
                vec.push_back( *i ); 
        } 
        return vec;
    }

        std::string brokerToStr(typename typeBroker::BROKER i) //<--Problem here !!
    {
        return typeBroker::listBroker[i];           
    }
};


struct brokerDisTradable  : broker<brokerDisTradable>{
    std::vector<std::string> listBroker;
    brokerDisTradable()
    {
        listBroker.push_back("BRIDGE1" );
        listBroker.push_back("BRIDGELONDON" );
        listBroker.push_back("RECY" );
        listBroker.push_back("CURRENEX" );
    }
    static const int nbBroker = 2;
    enum BROKER  { BRIDGE1, BRIDGELONDON, RECY, CURRENEX };
};
```

errro : error C2039: 'BROKER' : is not a member of broker_def::brokerDisTradable'

any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: A tip: Don't keep non-English comments in pasted code if you want people to understand what **you** think your code is doing.

Comment: broker_def is a namespace sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the derived type's internal types in the function declaration of the base, because the derived type's internal types aren't yet **defined**, the derived type is only **declared**.

There are a number of ways to get around this, including type traits parameter and additional template parameter, and they are perfectly discussed in *Base's using a type defined in Derived, in a Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* of *comp.lang.c++.moderated*: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/a99148265cb43680/b2581e058ffe8c91?#b2581e058ffe8c91

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the enum value as an index into an array, you could change the parameter type to brokerToStr to an int:

```
struct broker
{
    typedef T typeBroker;

    std::string brokerToStr(int i)
    {
        return typeBroker::listBroker[i];           
    }
```

Also, `typeBroker::listBroker[i]` won't work as `listBroker` is not a static member.

Comment: No, it will work as it is using CRTP. It is like any other member function of the class `brokerDisTradable`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are inheriting `brokerDisTradable` from `border<brokerDisTradable>`. Probably what you need to do is this:

```
struct brokerDisTradable {
    std::vector<std::string> listBroker;
    brokerDisTradable()
    {
        // ...
    }
    static const int nbBroker = 2;
    enum BROKER  { BRIDGE1, BRIDGELONDON, RECY, CURRENEX };
};

int main() 
{ 
  brokerDisTradable t;
  broker<brokerDisTradable> b;
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simplified example of the problem:

```
template <class T>
struct X
{
    void foo(typename T::Enum);
};

struct Y: X<Y>  //<-- X instantiate here, but at this point the compiler only knows
                //that a struct called Y exists, not what it contains
{
    enum Enum {Z}; 
};
```

As a possible workaround, perhaps move the enumeration out of Y and add a template parameter to X.

```
template <class T, class EnumType>
struct X
{
    void foo(EnumType);
};

enum Y_Enum {Z};

struct Y: X<Y, Y_Enum>
{  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`brokerDisTradable  : broker<brokerDisTradable>` seems to be an incomplete type (infinite heritage inside)

`struct brokerDisTradable` and using `broker<brokerDisTradable>` will work..